# How to setup/using GDB 7 on MacOS Lion with MacPorts

Tags: debugging, gdb, debug-symbols

I run into trouble using GDB 7 (7.3) on MacOS Lion.

What I did was:

```
$ sudo port install gdb
```

After that GDB was installed to: /opt/local/bin/ggdb

But when I try to execute GDB I always receive the following at start:

```
BFD: unable to read unknown load command 0x24
BFD: unable to read unknown load command 0x26
BFD: unable to read unknown load command 0x24
BFD: unable to read unknown load command 0x26
```

Further it tells me:

Reading symbols from  ... done.

but when I try to get for example a backtrace via 'bt' I only see unresolved function adresses. I tried to set the LIBRARY_PATH inside my application folder.

```
$ export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd`
```

but without success. The problems remain.

Using the default GDB 6.3 which is provided with Lion/Xcode works fine.

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: You might try cvs head, as there has been work this month getting BFD working with changes to mach-o on lion.  See the emails starting with the subject [mach-o.
I cannot comment on if lion will ever be supported in a future 7.3.x release, my guess is it will only be supported in 7.4
http://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2011-08/

Comment: I tried today 7.3.0.20110822 but I get the same BFD messages.

Comment: This problem still seems to persist.

Answer (score 1):

Try cgdb for now, it's actually pretty nice so far:

```
sudo port install cgdb
```

I don't claim to understand why the latest gdb sources have an issue on the mac, but I have the same issue as you and I tried cgdb and it works for me. Links for more information:

- http://cgdb.sourceforge.net/
- https://trac.macports.org/ticket/26450

Answer (score 0):

On Maverick follow this instructions that use homebrew. It seems that Apple's new system makes it hard to use gdb...
http://ntraft.com/installing-gdb-on-os-x-mavericks/